# Merge Object keys and nested array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

I have to implement new data in the form of a table into a legacy system. I just can't figure out how to merge the object values with the key and merge them into an array key

```
{
  "amount": [
    "33300.00",
    "43075.00",
    "93300.00",
    "193300.00",
  ],
  "rent_label": [
    "Due",
    "Due",
    "Due",
    "Due",
  ],
  "date": [
    "2020-04-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "2020-03-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "2020-02-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "2020-01-15T00:00:00.000Z",
  ]
}
```

What I already tried

```
let data = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
    let keyVal = Object.values(obj[key]).map((val) {
        return { [key]: val}
    })
    return data;
});
```

[image]

---

What I rather need is the array to be like this

```
[
  {
    "amount": "33300.00",
    "rent_label": "Due",
    "date": "2020-04-02T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "amount": "33300.00",
    "rent_label": "Due",
    "date": "2020-04-02T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "amount": "33300.00",
    "rent_label": "Due",
    "date": "2020-04-02T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
]
```

Comment: Can you show what you've already tried? Edit the question to include the code you've already written.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer Sure, 1sec

Comment: @DaneBrouwer mind taking a look now?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know that all of the properties have the same length, this would probably do the trick:

```
let obj = {}; //Put your object here
let length = Object.keys(obj).length;

let outputArr = [];

for(let i = 0;i<length;i++){
    outputArr = {};
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    for(let i = 0;i<length;i++){
        outputArr[i][key]=arr[key][i];
    }
});

console.log(outputArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

like that:

```
const DATA_LENGTH = 4;

const DATA = {
  "amount": ["33300.00","43075.00","93300.00","193300.00"],
  "rent_label": ["Due","Due","Due","Due"],
  "date": ["2020-04-02T00:00:00.000Z","2020-03-03T00:00:00.000Z","2020-02-04T00:00:00.000Z","2020-01-15T00:00:00.000Z"]
};

const newFormatData = [];

const dataKeys = Object.keys(DATA);

for (let i = 0; i < DATA_LENGTH; i++) {
  const obj = {};
  dataKeys.forEach(key => {
    obj[key] = DATA[key][i];
  });

  newFormatData.push(obj);
}
```

'newFormatData' variable now holds the new format data.

Answer (score 1):

```
const keys = Object.keys(obj);
const count = obj[keys[0]].length;
const array = [...Array(n).keys()].map(i => keys.reduce((acc, key) => ({...acc, [key]: obj[key][i]}), {}));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the size of the array is different based on the key, you can do this:

```js
const input = {
  "amount": ["33300.00", "43075.00", "93300.00", "193300.00"],
  "rent_label": ["Due", "Due", "Due", "Due", "TEST"],
  "date": ["2020-04-02T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-03-03T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-02-04T00:00:00.000Z", "2020-01-15T00:00:00.000Z"]
}

function merge (data) {
    const result = []
    const keys = Object.keys(data)
    const maxLength = Math.max(...keys.map(e => data[e].length))

    for (let index = 0; index < maxLength; index++) {
 result.push(keys.reduce((acc, value) => {
     acc[value] = data[value][index] || null
     return acc
 }, {}))
    }

    return result
}

console.log(merge(input))
```